# Rotate UIImageView Gradually using a timer

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation

I am attempting to rotate a UIImageView gradually using a timer, this code rotates it, but it doesn't seem like its rotating around the center of the image, as well adding the `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` to my code seems to stop all other code in the "main" method

```
#define radians(degrees) (degrees * M_PI/180)

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.016 target:self selector:@selector(main) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
-(void)main{
rotate++;
uiImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(rotate));
uiImageView.center = CGPointMake(uiImageView.center.x+1, uiImageView.center.y);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

Start the animation:

```
  CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
  rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
  rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2*M_PI)];
  rotation.duration = 1.0;// Speed
  rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;// Repeat forever.
  [imgViewCube.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
```

Stop the animation:

```
  [imgViewCube.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"Spin"];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked almost flawlessly, but when i stop the animation the image goes back to its original state, is there anyway to keep it in the rotated state?

Comment: what the `addAnimation:` method does is add the effect to the objects `presentationLayer`. Because of this when we are removing the animation, the view is going back to its initial state. Say suppose you want to move a n object from point A to Point B and persist the changed state at the end of animation, then you should first change the layers position to point B and then do an animation showing movement from Point A to Point B. -- continued

Comment: -- continued -> But in your case I don't think that can be done. So on stopping the animation I would suggest to get the current value from the ImageView's PresentationLayer and supply it to the ImageView's layer. within the same method. Cheers.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329426/how-can-i-rotate-a-uibutton-continuously-and-be-able-to-stop-it might be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

you can rotate it slowly specifying duration of animation

```
 NSTimeInterval duration = 1.5;
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^
{
    // set the final transform/freame/center here
    uiImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(rotate));
    uiImageView.center = CGPointMake(uiImageView.center.x+1, uiImageView.center.y);

} completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     NSLog(@"animation completed");
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
// this spin completes 360 degrees every 2 seconds
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations: ^(void){
                         uiImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(uiImageView.transform, M_PI / 2);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```